# How do I escape double quote and other troublesome characters in Powershell regex

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I've hit a snag in a script I'm putting together to download the latest installation packages without needing to use Chocolatey or Ketarin. Unfortunately a few utilities aren't provided at a direct download link and are hidden behind redirecting URLs, with the download URL expiring after 15 minutes. To complicate things a bit further, I'm doing this in PowerShell 2 as we have a few Vista machines in our office.

After researching other similar scenarios, it seems as though I can invoke the .NET WebClient to handle the download, though there isn't a progress bar. As I haven't found a sample of code to handle downloading files behind redirects after a certain amount of time that works with a .NET WebClient, I decided that what I could do is use a WebClient request to load the page, and then get the current direct download URL from the page using the following regex, and then use a regex to that URL to download the file. I've checked with regexr.com to verify that the regex catches the sample URL below.

Sample URL

```
<a href="https://www.example.com/randomstring003ejdjd38/dl/ProgramName.exe">CF DL here</a>
```

Regex

```
<a(?: [^>]*?)? href=(["'])([^\1]*?ProgramName*?)\1(?: .*?)?>.*?<\/a>
```

Unfortunately Powershell red flags this, as it seems to think the double quotes need to be terminated. After attempting to escape any red-flagged characters using backticks, I've wound up with the following, that throws a error saying that '?:' is not recognized as a term, cmdlet, etc.

```
$downloadLinkRegex = New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex (<a(?: [^>]*?)? href=(`[`"`'])(`[`^\1]*?ProgramName.exe*?)\1(?: .*?)?>.*?</a>)
if ("https://www.example.com/randomstring003ejdjd38/dl/ProgramName.exe" -match $downloadLinkRegex){
write-host "yay"
} else{
write-host "nope"}
```

Attempts to escape the ? using backticks fails also. Regex's are incredibly difficult for me, so at this point I'm out of ideas on how to make the ISE recognize that this is a valid regex, and that it doesn't need to be validated, and that it can be stored as the value of a variable to be called later on the contents of a webrequest.

If anyone could point out where I've gone wrong, or how to resolve the issue, I would be immensely grateful.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I can think of is by using the @" bla "@ block in powershell (I don't know the official name).
For example : 
$regex = @"
Insert regex here
"@
 Everything between the @" "@ block will be treated as a string value.

Comment: It is called *here-string*. And double quoted here-string expand variables `$VariableName` and subexpressions `$()`. So, you have to use single quoted here-string, to treat content as literal string value.

Answer (score 1):

I just removed the items PowerShell flags. I had to test several different ways to make sure this was the only way PowerShell would let me print to HTML. Even the ConvertTo-HTML won't bypass PowerShell's issues. It is a like a hybrid to HTML. I also noticed that PowerShell doesn't pay attention to blank space when you type so my real code has lots of spaces and empty lines to differentiate my script.

```
$My_HTML_table = "<!DOCTYPE html>
<head><title> My Excellent Page </title></head>
<H2> Table 1 </H2>
<text></text>
<table border=1;border-style:solid>
<tr>
<td colspan=1 style=color:blue;background-color:#CCCCCC;font-size:18;padding:5px> Cute Header </td>
</tr>"
$My_HTML_table > C:\File_Path\My_Excellent_HTML.html
```

Answer (score 0):

But it doesn't match on regexr.com ...? It fails because it thinks the `</a>` is the end of the regex. It also fails because it's trying to match ProgramNam(one or unlimited 'e') and ignoring the `.exe` bit. (And "must not match octal number 1"? That's probably not what you want in there (no, I didn't know that, I just saw it while scratching my head trying to decipher this on regex101.com)).

Anyway, to your question: PowerShell doesn't have regex literals, so you can't just write `<a(?: [^>]*?...` into the shell and have it work. They have to be strings.

But they don't have to be run through `New-Object System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex`.

e.g.

```
$url = '<a href="https://www.example.com/randomstring003ejdjd38/dl/ProgramName.exe">CF DL here</a>'

$pattern = "<a.*?href=[`"'](.*?)[`"'][^>]*>.*?</a>"

$url -match $pattern
$Matches[1]
```

I've quoted the string in double quotes around the outside. And then I've used a backtick to escape the double quotes inside the pattern.

Where the regex pattern is [explained much more helpfully here](https://regex101.com/r/yS4eZ6/1)

Comment: Looks like I miscopied the regex. Unfortunately the regex you provided grabs every single link on a page, instead of just the file name. I've tested it out here: http://regexr.com/3c0lf

I'm going to edit my original post with the corrected regex.

Answer (score 0):

I actually reworked the regex into something simpler to resolve the issue. While the URL continually changes the file name doesn't, so I focused on the filename, rather than the whole URL, and was able to grab the URL I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Looks good

```
$a='<a href="https://www.example.com/randomstring003ejdjd38/dl/ProgramName.exe">CF DL here</a>'
$a -match '(?<=ef=")[^"]+?(\w+).(exe|pdf)'
Iwr $matches[0] -outfile "$($matches[1]).$($matches[2])"
```